# How to update the button title?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
<DropdownButton bsStyle="default" title="No caret" noCaret id="dropdown-no-caret"> 
  <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
```

I took this example from the react-bootstrap components examples, https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns-nocaret

How would you update the button title when one of the menu item is selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the title using a state and add an `onChange` event to you `DropdownButton` to update the state

```
<DropdownButton bsStyle="default" title={this.state.btnTitle} noCaret id="dropdown-no-caret" onChange={this.handleChange}> 
  <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
```

Function:

```
handleChange = () => {
    var val = 'someValue';
    this.setState({btnTitle: val});  
}
```

This will change the title when you select any `MenuItem`. I hope this solution helps you

Comment: Thanks, for this tip. I was afraid to set a btnTitle state that will be updated if another DropdownButton is updated. I was able to get some results, but your answer is perfectly explained.